# How to set multiple xAxis.labels.align in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to set the **first** `xAxis label` align to `left` and the **last** `xAxis label` align to `right`.

How can I do that ?

Here is the options I have set, but every labels are align to left.

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    align : "left"
  }
}
```

I haven't found a way to do this, I thought it would have been possible through `series.data`, but I have seen nothing in [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) to do this.

- Do I have to **add an option** in `series.data` ?
- Do I have to **set something after it is displayed** with Javascript ?
- Do I have to **do something with the formatter** ?

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6Cpu/) of what I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `overflow: 'justify'` is the solution for what I want (first label align to the left and last to the right).

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    overflow: 'justify'
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6Cpu/1/).